# Why do scrollbars appear when using a SVG element inside a DIV?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

My aim is to have a `<div>` with a fixed size (dynamically set through JavaScript) that is only containing an `<svg>` element. When this `<svg>` is bigger than the parent `<div>` scrollbars should appear. When it's smaller, it's size should be set to those of the parent `<div>` - but no scrollbars should appear.

This isn't working as expected as a little bit of code can show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.svg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#editor').svg();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor" style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will create a nearly empty page, that contains a `<div>` with the fixed size of 500x500px - and a `<svg width="500" height="500">` inside. This SVG has scrollbars - although they are not needed as the size would be a perfect fit.

That this will only happen with a `<svg>` can be easily shown when the demo is modified to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.svg.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto"><div style="width:500px;height:500px"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So now a `<div>` is inside of the parent `<div>` of exactly the same size - and the scrollbars are appearing.

Can someone enlighten me, why the `<div>` and the `<svg>` are behaving differently?

And how I can embed an SVG inside the parent `<div>` without appearing scrollbars when the size is the same (and with appearing ones when the size gets bigger?)

Note: This is tested with Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: What if you wrap the editor like this? `<div style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto"><div id="editor"></div></div>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is because `div` is `display: block;` by default whereas `svg` is `display: inline;` so you're hitting an issue with the text baseline alignment that doesn't happen with the `div`.  Either of the following should remove the scrollbars if added to your CSS:

```
svg { display:block; }
```

Or;

```
svg { vertical-align: top; }
```

Comment: Thanks, `svg { display:block; }` is the correct solution in my case!

Comment: This solved a real headache for me. Would be nice if you explained a little bit more which is the baseline issue we're hitting here.

Comment: @elmart I'm not sure in a comment I can explain it any more than "text baseline alignment", try googling it for diagrams and stuff.