# Different Viewbox behaviour for inline vs embedded svg

Tags: css, svg, viewbox

I have an SVG image that I would like to keep as a separate file to my main html file. I am trying to make it work as an embed tag but have problems with different view box behaviour.
Below is the code that works as I would like. The viewbox takes up as much space as possible without overflowing the window

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

    <div>
         <!-- <embed src="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /> -->
        <svg 
            xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            version="1.1"
            xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
            xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
            viewBox="0 0 400 600">

            <g stroke-width="2">
                <rect height="600" width="400" stroke="#FF0" y="0" x="0" fill="#808080"/>
                <rect height="80" width="100" stroke="#808080" y="80" x="40" fill="#F60"/>
                <rect height="120" width="160" stroke="#808080" y="250" x="160" fill="#FC0" onclick="alert('one')"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

</body>
```

When I replace this with the embed tag that references this exact same text. The viewbox fills the width so that overflows the vertical dimension of the window.

Comment: Sounds more like a CSS question. Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4642713/109374.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the answer. By moving from a width attribute to setting the width in the style attribute the problem is resolved. 
html file contains a div and embed with style set widths.

```
<body style="overflow:none; margin:0" bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <div style="height:100%">
        <embed src="example.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="height:100%;width:100%"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the SVG file contains the view box

```
<svg 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
version="1.1"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
viewBox="0 0 400 600">

<g stroke-width="2">
    <rect height="600" width="400" stroke="#FF0" y="0" x="0" fill="#808080"/>
    <rect height="80" width="100" stroke="#808080" y="80" x="40" fill="#F60"/>
    <rect height="120" width="160" stroke="#808080" y="250" x="160" fill="#FC0" onclick="alert('one')"/>
</g>
```

There are still some odd behaviours when shrinking the window (it only resizes properly when the width is changed with the height) so if anyone has a better answer I would be keen to hear it

Comment: Have you investigated the `preserveAspectRatio` property? It may be responsible for the resize behavior you're seeing.